# NPE thrown after getting BundleContext from FrameworkUtil class

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I was following this tutorial to embed OSGi in my maven based application. I have one class file that creates and start the framework as mentioned [here](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html) and it works fine there as I am able to get BundleContext easily.

I have added this dependency in my pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.url</groupId>
        <artifactId>pax-url-mvn</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Now when I am running my whole framework and when it reaches to one of my new class file in the same maven based project where I need to use `BundleContext` so I thought I can use this piece of code to get the BundleContext`

`FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ModelProcessor.class).getBundleContext();`

but somehow the above code throws me `NullPointerException` and then I tried printing out to see what's happening-

`System.out.println(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ModelProcessor.class));`

So the above lines prints- `null`

Does anyone have any idea what does null means here in terms of OSGi and what I can do to resolve this issue?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelProcessor class is not loaded by OSGi classloader but by the Classloader of the main application (that embeds the OSGi framework). If you do the following you will see which classloader loaded the class:

```
System.out.println(ModelProcessor.class.getClassLoader().toString());
```

If you want to use the ModelProcessor class inside OSGi you should place it into a bundle and install it into the OSGi container.

Your next question would be probably: how to access classes from the main application that are in bundles in the OSGi container?

I do not know the answer without trying it but I have some guesses:

- I guess that a class or interface that is in the classpath of the main project (that embeds the OSGi container) will be on the boot classpath of the embedded OSGi container
- If my first guess is true you should take an interface into the main project and take an implementation of that interface into that bundle. You can instantiate the implementation in the Activator of the bundle and register it as a service
- In the main application you will be able to access the registered service based on the interface via the bundle context of the installed bundle (or the via the framework bundle context)

Till now this way the cause. Now if you need that bundle you can get it via the framework object. The framework object itself is a bundle as well. It has a bundleContext also. You can get your bundle based on the location value. The location identifies each bundle and you know the location of your bundle as you installed it :). If you do not know the location, you have to iterate through the bundles and check their symbolic names.

Comment: I am confuse slightly. I have started the osgi framework in my main application so I am assuming that all the classes within that project should be loaded by OSGi classloader? Right? If yes, then why it is not being loaded by OSGi classloader? And if not, then how can I make sure that all the classes in that main project should get loaded by OSGi classloader?

Comment: Once JVM starts and there is a classloader for it. After that your app starts and there is a classloader for that as well. The JVM is the parent of your app classloader. If a class is searched, it is searched first in the current classloader than in the parent. Now if you start an OSGi container it will open several classloaders but inside the container. I guess the classloader of your main app will be the parent of the OSGi boot classloader. Therefore if you use a class directly in your main app you can be sure that it does not come from OSGi.

Comment: OSGi is different from older solutions like JEE servers that classloaders are not in tree but in graph. If you draw on a paper, you can draw a tree until your main app (JVM - app) and under the app you can draw a graph (the OSGi bundles). You can only walk up or inside the OSGi container via bundle wirings.

Comment: I see... So that means I need to make framework as the static and use it in other classes to get the BundleContext and which I was trying to avoid... :(. I was following this [tutorial](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html)

Comment: Actually, I need to get the BundleContext in one of my class B... And I am not able to get it because that class is not loaded by OSGi class loader.. But in the class where my main application is in the same package which is claas A- I am starting the OSGi framework like it is mentioned in this [tutorial](http://njbartlett.name/2011/03/07/embedding-osgi.html). And in the same class A, I can get BundleContext using framework object.. But after I start my application and when the call goes to my class B in the same maven project, I need to use BundleContext somehow and if I am using

Comment: cont'd... BundleContext with the way I am using in the my question, it gives me NPE... So that means, I need to make framework object as static so that I can use BundleContext in class B.. Now it makes sense?

Comment: I see it now as you asked inside another question with a code snippet. However, I edited the answer to describe only the bundle context of that bundle if it is the one someone wants.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36062/discussion-between-techgeeky-and-balazs-zsoldos)